# Stack Snippet buttons are 100% wide

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, stack-snippets

I've just noticed, in the last couple minutes, the Stack Snippet buttons are 100% wide, as you can see the in Screenshots below:

#### Screenshot #1

[image: SS]

#### Screenshot #2

[image: SS2]

I found the class culprit for the issue, which is `btn-secondary`, that is being used in this [**cp.min.css**](https://cdn.sstatic.net/clc/styles/clc/cp.min.css?v=31fcdbbcd406). The only property being used is `width:100%`.

[image: SS3]

#### To me (but not for others as mentioned in comments below):

- After a few tests, looks like the [**cp.min.css**](https://cdn.sstatic.net/clc/styles/clc/cp.min.css?v=31fcdbbcd406) only loads when AdblockPlus is **enabled**, therefore causing the issue, else it won't load the file.

Can this be fixed?

**Tested in:**  Firefox 54.0.1 (32-bit and 64-bit) and Chrome 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: No repro using Chrome 59.0.3071.115 64-bit

Comment: Works fine in FF 54.0.1 (64-bit) and Chromium 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)

Comment: sorry guys question updated, found the issue

Comment: Can you please include a link to the post you're seeing this on?

Comment: @Rob any question/answer with stacksnippet, but [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37127123/change-color-of-underline-input-and-label-in-materialize-css-framework/37127156#37127156) for instances

Comment: Reproduced in 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit) on a Mac. (At first I thought it was fine but realized I have ABP disabled on Stack Overflow.)

Comment: This seems more like an adblock plus problem than a Stack Overflow problem to me. Adguard does not have this issue.

Comment: This was reproducing for me, but no longer

Comment: This seems to occur occasionally (FF54.0.1). I've no ABP installed, and some pages show Copy Snippet button incorrectly, some don't. Also Cancel button of question editing is 100% wide, but not on all pages.

Comment: Chrome 59 no Ad-block. Same issue as OP. Doesn't not occur every time, but very often.

Comment: Yea, I got this from today morning... This is crazy. It is inconsistently happening for me. Not sure when it is getting longer and shorter. Disabled and enabled ABP but no use.

Comment: @AlonEitan As others mentioned, not happening only when using ABP, to me from my  tests happened like that.

Comment: @dippas Ah, in that case and after your last edit my comment is now obsolete. Deleted. But it works fine on Windows 10, Chrome Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Looking at a fix ASAP, since this is indeed, on SO's side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alright, this *should* be fixed. I can't reproduce it anymore, even though I managed to make a setup where it appeared 100% of the time.

Thank you very much for the extremely well made bug report!

Comment: Now if questions on the site would have the same level of detail...

Comment: Thanks for the fix! Already tested it. can you add the tag `status-completed` ?

Comment: @Braiam appreciated your words, I always try to make detailed bug reports, and yes I would like to see the same level of detail on the site.

Answer (score 6):

There's a css rule in this stylesheet that's causing the width to be set to `100%`:

https://cdn.sstatic.net/clc/styles/clc/cp.min.css?v=31fcdbbcd406

The specific rule:

```css
.btn-clear, .btn-outlined, .btn-secondary {
    position:relative;
    padding:8px;
    min-height:unset;
    width:100%;        /* <-- Here's the culprit */
    border-radius:2px;
    border-width:1px;
    border-style:solid;
    font-weight:400;
    font-family:inherit;
    line-height:1.4;
    text-decoration:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    outline:0;
    touch-action:manipulation;
    transition:all .3s cubic-bezier(.165,.84,.44,1)
}
```

This stylesheet is only loaded when the **`.clc-cp-container`** element is rendered, which contains a specific job offer.
This element gets added to the page randomly, regardless of the presence of adblock.

In other words, this is an SO / SE bug, and has nothing to do with any adblocker plugin.

Comment: Just clarifying a bit more, it's a SO jobs ad problem, unrelated to adblock.

Comment: I was aware the culprit, as you can see in my question, but oddly to me would work if I disabled the ADP, and I did that a few times, that's I thought was an ABP issue. Now I noticed the issue is related to SO Jobs. Thanks. This needs to be fixed. It really looked like  an adblock issue, but hey you are totally right, I've tested it.